# To transfer 10 RtpPackets to server using 10 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I made a client/server where the client program makes 10 threads containing a rtpPacket.
Each is sent to the server.The code for both Server and  client is below.
At Server few packets are not received and some received packets are incorrect.
Any help would be of great use.

```
enter code here

Server.java

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Server
{

 DatagramSocket ss;

 InetAddress add;

 DatagramPacket dph,dpp;

 int port;

 static int i=0;

 public void receivePacket() throws Exception
 {

     ss=new DatagramSocket(10000);
     byte b[][]=new byte[10][102400];
     byte b1[][]=new byte[10][102400];
     while(true)
     {
     dph=new DatagramPacket(b[i],b[i].length);
     ss.receive(dph);
     dpp=new DatagramPacket(b1[i],b1[i++].length);
     ss.receive(dpp);
     add=dph.getAddress();
     port=dph.getPort();
     ss.connect(add,port);
     RetrievePacket1 ob=new RetrievePacket1();
     ob.getRtpHeader(dph.getData(),dpp.getData());
     if(i==10)
         i=0;
     }
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {

     Server ob=new Server();
     ob.receivePacket();
 }
}
class RetrievePacket1 
{

   int version;

   int padd;

   int mark;

   int ext;

   int cc;

   int pType;

   int sequence;

   int time;

   int ssrc;

   int header_size=12;

    public void getRtpHeader(byte []header,byte []payload)
    {

        System.out.println(payload[0]+" "+payload[1]);
      cc=header[0]&15;
      ext=(header[0]>>4)&1;
      padd=(header[0]>>5)&1;
      version=(header[0]>>6)&3;
      pType=header[1]&127;
      mark=(header[1]>>7)&1;
      sequence = unsigned_int(header[3]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[2]);
      time= unsigned_int(header[7]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[6]) + 65536*unsigned_int(header[5]) + 16777216*unsigned_int(header[4]);
      ssrc=unsigned_int(header[8]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[9]) + 65536*unsigned_int(header[10]) + 16777216*unsigned_int(header[11]);
        System.out.println("Version: "+version);
        System.out.println("Padding: "+padd);
        System.out.println("Extension: "+ext);
        System.out.println("CRC Count: "+cc);
        System.out.println("Marker: "+mark);
        System.out.println("Payload Type: "+pType);
        System.out.println("Sequence Number: "+sequence);
        System.out.println("Timestamp: "+time);
        System.out.println("SSrc: "+ssrc);
        System.out.println(version+" "+padd+" "+ext+" "+cc+" "+mark+" "+" "+pType+" "+sequence);
        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(ssrc);
        System.out.println("Hello people"+Server.i);
    }   
     public static int unsigned_int(int nb) 
     {

          if (nb >= 0) 
              return(nb);
          else 
              return(256+nb);
     }
}

Client.java

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client 
{

    DatagramSocket cs;

    InetAddress add;

    DatagramPacket dph,dpp;

    static int packet=10;

    static int seq=100;

    static int timestamp=500;

    public void sendPacket(byte []header,byte []payload) throws Exception
    {        

        cs=new DatagramSocket();
        add=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        //add=InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.30");
        dph=new DatagramPacket(header,header.length,add,10000);
        dpp=new DatagramPacket(payload,payload.length,add,10000);
       /* packet++;
        seq++;
        timestamp++;*/
        cs.send(dph);
        cs.send(dpp);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        Runnable ob=new RtpHeader1();
        Thread t[]=new Thread[10];
        Client ob1=new Client();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            t[i]=new Thread(ob);
            t[i].start();
            //t[i].join();
            //ob1.sendPacket(t[i].header,t[i].payload);
        }



    }
}
class RtpHeader1 implements Runnable
{

   int version;

   int padd;

   int mark;

   int ext;

   int cc;

   int pType;

   int sequence;

   int time;

   int ssrc;

   int header_size=12;

   public byte header[];


  public int payload_size;

  public byte[] payload;

   public void makeRtpPacket(int pType,int frameNo,int time,byte []data,int data_length)
   {

       version=2;
       padd=mark=ext=cc=ssrc=0;
       sequence=frameNo;
       this.time=time;
       System.out.println(pType+"\t"+frameNo+"\t"+time);
       this.pType=pType;
       header=new byte[header_size];
       header[0] = (byte)(version << 6);
       header[0] = (byte)(header[0] | padd << 5);
       header[0] = (byte)(header[0] | ext << 4);
       header[0] = (byte)(header[0] | cc);
       header[1] = (byte)(header[1] | mark << 7);
       header[1] = (byte)(header[1] | this.pType);
       header[2] = (byte)(sequence >> 8);
       header[3] = (byte)(sequence & 0xFF);
       header[4] = (byte)(this.time >> 24);
       header[5] = (byte)(this.time >> 16);
       header[6] = (byte)(this.time >> 8);
       header[7] = (byte)(this.time & 0xFF);
       header[8] = (byte)(ssrc >> 24);
       header[9] = (byte)(ssrc >> 16);
       header[10] = (byte)(ssrc >> 8);
       header[11] = (byte)(ssrc & 0xFF); 
    payload_size = data_length;
    payload = new byte[data_length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data_length; i++)
        payload[i] = data[i];

  }

    public byte[] getData() 
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       // System.out.println("Enter 3 data");
        byte data[]=new byte[3];
        int i=0;
        while(i<3)
            data[i++]=1;//sc.nextByte();
        return data;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
        byte data[]=new byte[3];
        data=getData();
        makeRtpPacket(Client.packet++,Client.seq++,Client.timestamp++,data,data.length);
        new Client().sendPacket(header, payload);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

To run
Run `Server.java` followed by `Client.java`
Preferrably use Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc for [DatagramPacket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html):

"Multiple packets sent from one machine to another might be routed differently, and might arrive in any order. Packet delivery is not guaranteed."

Sinds multiple clients are sending at the same time and the server expects two different packets (`dph` and `dpp`) in order, a `DatagramSocket` does not appear to be the right tool for the job. Try using client [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)s connecting to a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).

Comment: The code runs on a single machine, So there should'nt be any packet loss